# Oracle APEX 5.1 "PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query" Charts

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a problem with new charts in Oracle APEX 5.1. I need to do chart from PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query, but it only works if I do it with exact parameters and no page or app variables. If I use variable as parameter, then i get error "Parsing returned query results in "ORA-06550: line 16, column 37: ORA-00936: missing expression".", but in legacy chart the same function with parameters works just fine...

for example this source for chart works

```
return CHARTS.GET_IOPROFILE_CHART(1, 1701);
```

but this does not

```
return CHARTS.GET_IOPROFILE_CHART(:P22_PROFILE, :G_TEST_ID);
```

Can enybody please help me, I just do not see what is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

If you use parameter you must insert all parameters on **Page items to submit**

Comment: Yes I know...I have it that way, but it does not work regardless

Comment: Try to add more detail complete PL/Sql function might help.

Comment: Try to check your query.ORA-000936 have 2 common cause. When you forget list of the column names in your SELECT statement, or when you omit the FROM clause of the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

The new jet charts in Oracle Apex do not work exactly the same way as the anycharts.

I assume you are attempting to return a query through function because you have a dynamic set of series. In the new charts, for Dynamic series, you no longer need to return a query. In the source of the region, place a query that returns your link, label, series, and value columns (previously, any charts only could take link, label, value columns).

Then, in the series properties, for source, select region source. In column mapping, map series name, label, and value columns.

Good luck.